# Why do controllers need multiple format renderings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please explain why do we need this code in a controller? What is the significance of this block of code?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you to format output differently depending on the format the user/caller requests.  If you were to access `http://yourhost/controller/index.html`, the controller would respond with the ERB template `index.html.erb` (or HAML or whatever).  If you were to access `http://yourhost/controller/index.json`, it would respond with the JSON template `index.json.erb`.

This allows you to have a single controller action that can prepare data and then select the view for rendering based on the requested format.

Comment: Note that you don't have to do this.  If your site is HTML-only, you can remove all that code you pasted, and just fall through to the default rendering, which will be the HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

Defines mime types that are rendered by default when invoking respond_with.
So basically, this means that your controller action can be hit in different formats(html, json in your case), and still provide data back to whatever is calling it. This is helpful for API development, and many other things. 
For example: You want to get a json list of all your users to do something with javascript. You'd call /users.json and this would go to your user_controller#index action and know to render a json object of all your users.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is scaffold generated, and provides a way to render `*.html` and `*.json` views for your controller, making it easy to have access to data for implementing an API or normal views for your web application.

You can also create XML output:

```
format.xml  { render xml: @users }
```

and other formats like PDF, or DOC, depending on the gems you are using.

See the [Rails Guide Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) for more information.